# Discord auto follow channel message(without being an admin) and then resend it to another server

Tags: automation, discord, message, sendmessage, website-monitoring

Is there a way for people who is only a member in a discord channel, have discord to auto send the new message happening in the said channel, to a channel on my own server?

Note I can not add anything to the said channel, my discord account is not a bot, able to read and copy/paste the new messages in the said channel.

How do I do this? Can I change my personal account into an bot account, without losing the functionality of a regular account, such as being in multiple servers, manually send messages etc, to achieve this?

Any avenue to accomplish this goal work! Thank you so much!

Tried to used zapier, but it informs me that it needs admin permission/add a bot to the said channel that I don't owe